# Unable to add site columns including (created By, Created date & latest version) to my Enterprisewiki content type or to my enterprisewiki page layout

Tags: 2013, development, sharepoint-server, publishing-site

I have the following inside SharePoint 2013:-

1. Publishing site collection.
2. I used the Enterprise Wiki template.
3. Currently I want to add the following site columns to my EnterPriseWiki page layout:-

   - created By,
   - Modified By,
   - Created date
   - & latest version

But I cannot find a way for doing this. For example when I opened the page layout using SharePoint designer, I cannot find these fields inside the Page fields or Control fields’ toolbox, as follow:-

[image]

Also when I go to the library setting and I tried to add these column to the enterprisewiki content type,  I also cannot find these columns in the column drop down as follow:-

[image]

So can anyone advice on this please?

also i tried to understand how the message at the top of a wiki page is being constructed , seems it uses the following code inside the page layout :-

```
<SharePoint:FormattedString FormatText="<%$Resources:wss,wikidiff_lastmodifiedby%>" runat="server">
<SharePoint:FormField id="modifiedFieldCtrl" ControlMode="Display" FieldName="Modified" runat="server"/
```

so can i follow the same steps to add my intended columns ?

Thanks

Comment: where exactly do you want to add this columns? to which library?

Comment: i want to display these columns when add/edit/view any wiki page. currently i will get two columns by defualt the page rating and wiki category. so i want to add these columns to be above those fields and of course these fields should not be editable by users , unlike the page rating and the wiki category.